# What is the relationship between Sabbath 31a and Matthew 7:12? (Golden Rule)

Tags: matthew, jesus, nt-use-of-hebrew-bible

In the Talmud, Sabbath 31 a it reads, among other things:

> [Hillel said] That which is hateful to you do not do to another; **that is the entire Torah, and the rest is its interpretation. Go study.**

Now this appears to be a reference to what is said in Tobit (4:15):

> See thou never do to another what thou wouldst hate to have done to thee by another.

But Jesus states the positive form of the Golden Rule in Matthew 7:12 and uses it, like those who wrote *Sabbath*, to sum up the whole Law, with very similar words:

> All things therefore whatsoever you would that men should do to you, do you also to them. **For this is the law and the prophets.**

Who is taking from whom? Did they come up with this independently? Is the Talmud putting the words of Jesus into the mouth of Hillel (whose grandchild is Gamaliel, whom we might be familiar with), or is it possible that Jesus even learned from Hillel when He was younger? Or again, is Jesus expanding the maxim by inverting it (which naturally goes beyond simply refraining oneself, but actively doing, helping etc.) as He does with other already known laws and rules?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I do not know the answer to this very good question.  However, I strongly suspect that Jesus was sufficiently familiar with Hillel (as would His audience) that He changed it to fit with His theology.

Comment: Almost all the teachings of Jesus are recorded in Talmud. Quite a few of them are an abridged version of what Talmud narrates Some are verbatim quoted by Jesus. A few were misquoted by the Greek translator.

Comment: You may see some of the videos of Rabbi Michael Skobac where he does a review of the verse of the Greek text by verse review to see how it ties or does not tie with Tanakh.  

https://www.youtube.com/user/tenaktalk/videos

Comment: One can wonder if it ever is possible to follow one of the two interpretations of rule, without following the other? Or do the two rules, the negative and the positive, mean the same? One just being a rephrasing of the other.

Comment: @YedduPrasad Tanak Talk is a woefully anti-Christian circle of post-Christian, Talmud-following Jews who are explicitly and markedly invested in destroying the missionary effort of Christians to spread the gospel of Christ. They are therefore heavily biased and unreliable and unrepresentative of 'the Jewish' interpretation of Scripture — unless by 'Jewish' you mean 'expressly and explicitly antichirist and post-Christian Jewish interpretation?' Especialy insofar as they contradict pre-Christian Jews on the same matters.

Comment: @Sola Gratia, Yes, when the Christians tried to convert Jews to Christianity in 1960s, they responded aggressively and got them a bad reputation. Now they are well-read in the Greek text and are using their Tanakh knowledge to share their point of view. Please consider this verse Micah 4:2 Many nations will come and say, “Come, let us go up to the mountain of the Lord, to the temple of the God of Jacob. He will teach us his ways, so that we may walk in his paths.” The law will go out from Zion, the word of the Lord from Jerusalem. – Yeddu Prasad 1 hour ago

Comment: @Sola Gratia, I am a Christian for 53 years and not biased toward the Jewish teachings. I am seeking the truth. I only focus on Tanakh(Chabad version) and the greek text (NIV) to see if there are inconsistencies. The key for me is to understand what G-d expects from me and try to do it to the best of my abilities. Any contradiction to Tanakh, I examine carefully and ask questions in forums like this to see what others have found. g-d Bless.

Answer (score 1):

**Babylonian Talmud**

It is difficult to ascertain with certainty the age of a statement the Babylonian Talmud:

- It could go back all the way to the attributed speaker
- It could be a statement based on what the attributed speaker said,
  but has been developed/expanded upon since that time
- It could be an incorrect attribution

Much of the material was in oral circulation (and/or through now lost written sources) for many years, making its origin difficult to trace.

**The statement was in circulation**

For purposes of this answer I will acknowledge that there is no reason why Rabbi Hillel *couldn't* have said this. Furthermore, the idea (of the negative Golden Rule) is found in earlier sources as well, such as Isocrates of ancient Greece (4th century B.C.):

> Do not do to others that which angers you when they do it to you (see
> [here](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0144%3Aspeech%3D3%3Asection%3D61) 3.61)

Tobit (or its sources) may be older than Isocrates; the exact  date is unknown.

Jesus frequently dialogued with the religious leaders of His day, and so it is reasonable to accept that He would have been familiar with this idea.

**Negative vs. Positive Golden Rule**

Both the negative and positive form of the Golden Rule have their roots in the Old Testament:

> Thou shalt not avenge, nor bear any grudge against the children of thy
> people, but thou shalt love thy neighbour as thyself: I am the Lord.
> (Lev. 19:18)

The positive form of the Golden Rule "All things therefore whatsoever you would that men should do to you, do you also to them" may indeed be original to Jesus--there is no definite usage (to my knowledge) of the positive form from an earlier date.

The positive form is an insightful development upon the negative form (negative form was found in Greece, Hillel, Tobit, etc) in that it isn't enough *not* to do ill; we are called upon to *do* good.

**Conclusion**

Whether Jesus learned the negative form of the Golden Rule through the disciples of Hillel or other means, it was an idea circulating in the eastern Mediterranean at His time. (For this reason, I doubt the Talmud derived the negative form of the Golden Rule from Jesus, though I can't rule it out completely)

I suggest that Jesus is expanding the maxim to show the type of life His followers should live, much as He did with other commands in the Sermon on the Mount.

What is the relationship between Sabbath 31a and Matthew 7:12?

The answer is uncertain, but an educated guess would be this:

- There is no direct literary relationship
- The basic ideas of each have common, older sources
- Jesus took the idea a step further

Comment: If Anti-semitism is atrocious, then the view of Gentiles by Jews of the ancient world (and thus Gentile philosophers) was far worse — Tobit is set in the 8th century BC; and textual criticism is very often too willing to date something late in order to satisfy its own question-begging standards, so I wouldn't be too quick to assume that Isocrates committed this maxim to writing "before" Tobit or its sources (since to assert as much is to claim that Jews copied from pagan philosophers, or that oral or written but forgotten source tradition is non-existent).

Comment: I'm not sure the question has a 'the' answer, but since your answer doesn't tell me any more than I already knew (or which was implied by the question itself), I can only give you an upvote.

Comment: @Sola Gratia you make a fair point about Tobit which I hadn't called out in my answer - I edited to acknowledge this. I agree that question-begging has at least sometimes cast doubt on the chronological reliability of textual criticism. Sorry I can't offer a more definitive answer. In any event, I think the origin of the idea is decidedly Jewish (Leviticus 19:18)

Comment: @SolaGratia I guess I could have answered more directly =). I amended my conclusion to acknowledge that I don't think there's a direct literary relationship between the two.

Comment: Note that in Luke's 10's version, it is the Torah scholar who expresses the Golden Rule. This indicates that the summary of the Torah used by Jesus was already known.

Comment: @DanFefferman I'm not sure I follow your point. The Torah scholar doesn't give the Golden Rule, he quotes Leviticus 19. Sure, the Golden Rule can be seen as an expansion or application of the Leviticus passage, but I would not consider them identical teachings.

Answer (score 0):

A key implication here is that the Golden Rule was well known is Jesus' time. We cannot know for certain whether the chicken of Hillel's summary  resulted in the egg of Jesus' version or vice versa. But there is evidence in the Bible (even ignoring Tobit) that the Golden Rule was known prior to Jesus' teaching it.  Indeed  Jews of the Hillel School seem to have already known Jesus' similar summary.

The best example of the widespread influence of the Golden Rule among Jews at the time is found in Luke's description (Luke 10) of the scholar's question that precedes the parable of the Good Samaritan:

> An expert in the law stood up to test Jesus. “Teacher,” he said, “what
> must I do to inherit eternal life?” 26 He said to him, “What is
> written in the law? What do you read there?” 27 He answered, “You
> shall love the Lord your God with all your heart and with all your
> soul and with all your strength and with all your mind and your
> neighbor as yourself.” 28 And he [Jesus] said to him, “You have given the
> right answer; do this, and you will live.”

In Mark 12, there is a similar dynamic. Here it is a scribe who asks. He approves of Jesus's answer and declares “You are right, Teacher... this is much more important than all whole burnt offerings and sacrifices.” When Jesus saw that he answered wisely, he said to him, “You are not far from the kingdom of God.”

In Matthew 22, Pharisees question Jesus after they see that he "had silenced the Sadducees." He gives his summary of the Law, and they proceed to ask him about his teaching regarding the Messiah.

Thus, each of the synoptic Gospels describes a situation in which Torah scholars are impressed with Jesus teaching summarizing the Law, and in one case the person actually gives Jesus the summary himself, rather than agreeing with Jesus teaching of it. Incidentally, [Hillel was also famous](https://www.newworldencyclopedia.org/entry/Hillel_the_Elder) for his broadminded attitude toward Gentiles and his emphasis on the spirit rather than the letter of the Law.) Hillel-followers would not be offended by Jesus' attitude toward the law nearly so much as their opponents from the [School of Shammai](https://www.newworldencyclopedia.org/entry/Shammai).

**Given Hillel's fame as the leader of one of two prominent rabbinical schools at the time, we can conclude that his teaching and attitude toward the Law were well known. It produced a culture among Hillel's disciples among the Pharisees in which this key part of Jesus' teaching would be normal.**